# Template initialisation causes stack overflow

Tags: c#, wpf, stack-overflow, datatemplate, contentpresenter

I have a DataModel like so :

```
public class Node
    {
        public List<Node> Children { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public Node(string _name, params Node[] _children)
        {
            Name = _name;
            Children = new List<Node>(_children);
        }
    }
```

I now want to define a View for this model (I'm not using a TreeView for reasons out of scope of this question), that allows people to use it in one of two ways.

Example 1 : Default layout, the content should auto Expand

```
<NodeView DataContext="{Binding Root}"/>
```

The above should expand the node tree in the same way a treeview would, i.e recursively going down the Node and its children creating new views for each one.

Example 2 : Allow people to manually set the content

```
<NodeView DataContext="{Binding Root}">
    <StackPanel>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Children[0].Name"/>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Children[1].Name"/>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Children[2].Name"/>
    </StackPanel>
</NodeView>
```

The above now won't expand, but only show the first three child nodes.

I thought I could do this with the following Custom Control, but I get a stackoverflow exception, what am I doing wrong?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type l:NodeView}">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <GroupBox>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <l:NodeView />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </GroupBox>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type l:NodeView}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   Grid.Column="1" />
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                                          Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Here is a link to the project if anyone finds that easier to use 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j32mm7gave17v7j/NodeView.zip

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes basically from your Style. You set the Content. However you should specify the Template and the ItemTemplate.

The first one will descripe how NodeView is visuallised: a textblock with a list of children.
The second will describe how your children nodes are visualised: NodeView control.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type l:NodeView}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type l:NodeView}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                               Grid.Column="1" />
                    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <l:NodeView Content="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You will notice that it looks a bit strange with no ContentPresenter. But that's a result of a non appropriate base class of the NodeView. Content control is usually used for a single content but here you have a content with children items.

By the way it is not the only way you can write it. It is possible to keep the default template for the Template and to put the entire thing in to the ContentTemplate of the NodeView.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type l:NodeView}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type l:NodeView}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                               Grid.Column="1" />
                    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <l:NodeView Content="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In the main window you should use Content property and not the DataContext.

PS: I wrote the code without testing so not sure it works out of the box.

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question, your styles are a fixed implementation of Example 1, .. I'm wanting the control to have that as its default layout, but also allow people to define the content manually like in Example 2. I've edited the question a little to make this more clear

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be, that you reference the control you're templating, in the style of the control itself.
So when WPF tries to create the style, it tries to initialize it, whereby it has to create the datatemplate, so it has to initialize the style... and there you have your loop.

The only way around this, that I found, was to set your default content by code, like this:

```
public NodeView()
    {
            var dt = FindResource("DefaultNodeContent") as DataTemplate;
            var lb = new ItemsControl();
            lb.ItemTemplate = dt;
            var binding = new Binding("Children");
            lb.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);

            var gb = new GroupBox();
            gb.Content = lb;
            this.Content = gb;

    }
```

For this, you'd have to add a resource dictionary to you app

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5">
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultNodeContent">
        <l:NodeView DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And then your style would change to:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type l:NodeView}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type l:NodeView}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   Grid.Column="1" />
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                                          Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Hope this helps.